# MapDB list type?

Tags: java, mapdb

I am using mapdb 3.0.7

I see various hash map and tree map storage types here.

But I have a use case that needs a `List<String>` to be persisted to mapdb.

Does this version of mapDB even support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapDB does have a HashSet object which seems like all we have to work with.

See http://www.mapdb.org/javadoc/latest/mapdb/org/mapdb/DB.HashSetMaker.html

I don't think there is any List data structure in mapdb 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I am using mapdb 3.0.8:

```
DB db = DBMaker.fileDB(new File("base.mapdb")).closeOnJvmShutdown().make();
List<String> list = db.indexTreeList("some_list", Serializer.STRING).createOrOpen();
```

Comment: this is the right answer. [IndexTreeList](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/blob/release-3.0/src/main/java/org/mapdb/IndexTreeList.kt) implements [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).